# Update scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I successfully installed scikit-learn 0.23.1 with pip.

```
pip list
```

```
scikit-learn                  0.23.1
scipy                         1.4.1
Send2Trash                    1.5.0
serverfiles                   0.3.0
setuptools                    47.3.1.post20200616
SimpleITK                     1.2.4
six                           1.15.0
sklearn                       0.0
sklearn-contrib-lightning     0.5.0
sklearn-contrib-py-earth      0.1.0
sklearn-crfsuite              0.3.6
```

In python, it seems that the version of scikit-learn is 0.21.3

```
import sklearn
import numpy
import scipy
import joblib
import threadpoolctl
from platform import python_version 
print('python:            ',python_version())
print('threadpoolctl:     ',threadpoolctl.__version__)
print('scipy:             ',scipy.__version__)
print('joblib:           ',joblib.__version__)
print('scikit-learn:     ',sklearn.__version__)
print('numpy:            ',numpy.__version__)
```

The result is:

```
python:             3.6.10
threadpoolctl:      2.1.0
scipy:              1.4.1
joblib:            0.15.1
scikit-learn:      0.21.3
numpy:             1.16.1
```

Comment: What are your environments where you are running both things?

Comment: which is the `pip` binary used to install the package? which is the `python` binary used to run the code snippet? is the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set? if yes, what's the value?

Comment: I used the anaconda prompt to install scikit-learn 0.23.1 (`pip install scikit-learn == 0.23.1`) then I wrote  `pip list` to verify the installation.
I used the netbook jupyter to display the sklean version (`print (sklearn .__ version__)`). 
I haven't defined any environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I have two versions of python, the first is included in anaconda and the second outside of anaconda
I solved the problem by:

1. uninstall of two versions
2. installation only anaconda